# Can we use Sqoop in Cloudera to import data onto Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, sqoop

One of many parts of Hadoop ecosystem is SQOOP which is to get data from dbms and load in Hadoop. I see that sqoop component is also present in Cassandra to import data, so was wondering if we can use the SQOOP provided by Cloudera to import data into Cassandra. Should there be any significant changes required.

Any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop present in Datastax Enterprise has `--cql-import` switch, which accepts `cassandra-host, cassandra-username, cassandra-password..etc` as parameters.

While the sqoop by default has `--import` switch which will not allow you to use the above parameters.

Comment: small **u** in `Undefined_variable` will make your name more cool....:P